# pseudo selectors in html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have added colour only to the alternate list items using the `nth-child(odd)` pseudo-class, but I don't know why the color is displayed out of the border [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw3r8yjk/1/).

```
header li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:cyan;
}
```

Full demo:

```css
header li {
  list-style: none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: black;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: deeppink;
  color: purple;
}
header li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This is simple demonstration of different ways of using Pseudo-Selectors</h1>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Sambar</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Idli</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Mysore Bonda</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Cashew Bonda</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Pesarattu Upma</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Cornflakes</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Thai curry</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Parmesan Garlic</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Honey BBQ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Pappu Charu</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</header>
```

Comment: Your `li` elements don't have a set width, so they are taking up the entire page. The darker blue areas are not doing this because they are `<a>` elements, and you've done `a:link, a:visited { width: 150px; }`. What exactly do you want to be cyan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply it to anchor(`a`) elements:

```
header li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```css
header li {
  list-style: none;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: black;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: deeppink;
  color: purple;
}
header li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<title>Pseudo-Selectors</title>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>This is simple demonstration of different ways of using Pseudo-Selectors</h1>
    <ol>

      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Sambar</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Idli</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Mysore Bonda</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Cashew Bonda</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Pesarattu Upma</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Cornflakes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Thai curry</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Parmesan Garlic</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Honey BBQ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">Pappu Charu</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </header>
</body>
```